# Trying to integrate python with arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to make an Arduino program to blink LED without using the in-built delay() function. But then I also want to use Python to do the work in back-end sending instructions to the Arduino. How do I send the current LED state i.e LOW or HIGH to python to do the work?

I have written the following code yet and I don't know if Serial.print() does the work or not?

```
import serial
from serial.serialutil import SerialException
import time, sys

try:
    board = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
except SerialException:
    print("Board doesn't seem to be connected. Serial Exception occured.")
    sys.exit()

prevTime = time.time()
freq = 0.5
LEDSTATE = 0

while True:
    currTime = time.time()

    LEDSTATE = int(board.read())
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if currTime-prevTime >= freq:
        prevTime = currTime
        if LEDSTATE == 0:
            LEDSTATE = 1
        else:
            LEDSTATE = 0

    board.write(LEDSTATE)
```

This is the arduino code:

```
const int ledPin = 13;
int ledState = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // not initialized until board connected with Serial port.
  while(!Serial.available());

  //send the present state of LED.
  Serial.println(ledState);
  
  //read the state to which LED is going to be changed.
  ledState = Serial.readString().toInt();
  
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
}
```

Comment: *I don't know if Serial.print() does the work or not*. I'm not sure I understand this comment, sorry. Does your `Serial.println(ledState)` print what is expected? Rather than put that print statement before reading the port, I would put it after so you know what you just read. I/O is buffered on the PC so you might need to send a newline (`\n`) after sending the state, in which case you may want to use `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` on the Arduino.

Comment: By the way, avoiding `delay()` is good, but another way to do it is in your `loop()` check `millis()`. There are a number of examples online for using `millis()` to count time, which avoids blocking with `delay()` (such as [Using `millis()` for timing](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/using-millis-for-timing)

Comment: But im already doing this in python which is somewhat similar to millis() in arduino. Should I do it in arduino only?

Comment: It seems somewhat excessive to use an external system just to get a reasonable delay in your Arduino, if that's the only purpose it is serving.